# Difference between two ways of Using Try blocks

Tags: vb.net

If I need to record data on 3 tables of the same database the next two ways works the same for me

**Nestled 1**

```
Try
    Using (conn)
    conn.Open()

        Try
            'Handle Table 1
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try

        Try
            'Handle Table 2
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try

        Try
            'Handle Table 3
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try

    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString())
End Try
```

**Nestled 2**
Using block is the main

```
Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(SQLiteConnStr)
    Try
        conn.Open()

        Try
            'Handle Table 1
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try

        Try
            'Handle Table 2
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try

        Try
            'Handle Table 3
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Using
```

**The two ways are the same or one is better because a better handle on "Catch ex as Exception?**

Comment: The first one would also catch exceptions in the destructor of `conn`. The second version disposes `conn` only after leaving the `try` block (i.e. the variable is still valid in the catch statement). Otherwise, they are equal.

Comment: The first one is not going to dispose of the connection at all.  `End Using` disposes of things created with `Using` - the first one creates `conn` outside it

Comment: So, a better way is to wrap all the "Nestled 2" with another Try - Catch?

Comment: @Plutonix Then why I don´t need to close the conn on the first sample? I tested the code and If I run the code and then I run similar code again I don't recieve any warning about DataBase already opened

Comment: You can have more than one connection open at a time to the DB.  If you examine `conn` after the `End Using` (just hold the mouse over it) you will see it is not `Nothing` thus not disposed and *that* Using block isnt doing anything.  Not disposed, you could run out of connections eventually.

Comment: Understood, then a better way is to wrap all the "Nestled 2" with another Try - Catch to catch exceptions in the destructor of conn?